# Why does my corrupted buffer appear in chunks of 8x8 pixels?

Tags: java, processing, jogl, corrupt

I've been working on a Processing/Java/JOGL piece lately in which I'm drawing to an offscreen buffer.  When I start the program, I see some beautiful glitchiness (see image below).

I assume this is leftover data in the buffer address spaces from the last time I ran the program. The smallest square chunks are 8x8 pixels. It seems that bigger chunks tile the 8x8px squares in 4x4 metachunks, and those are also tiled 4x4 into überchunks. I'm on a 64-bit operating system.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm seeing this glitched-out image on program init? Did I pretty much already answer my question?  (Mostly just curious what's going on under the hood.)

**EDIT:** added a zoomed-in version of the image, since SO doesn't have any sort of click-to-zoom on images.

[image: My glitchtastic startup screen.]
[image: Zoomed-in shot of the same.]

**EDIT:** @SuperKael asked for code.  It's difficult to isolate what might be creating this effect, because the rendering is mainly abstracted away into Processing's implementation of JOGL.  The following is an attempt to explain what's happening within my code:

The map background image is loaded as a `PImage`:

```
PImage backgroundImage = pApplet.loadImage(pathToImage);
```

The buffer for content to be drawn on top of that background image is initialized:

```
PGraphics foregroundBuffer = pApplet.createGraphics(w, h, PApplet.OPENGL);
```

Foreground images, to render within the buffer, are loaded:

```
for (String path : foregroundImagePaths) {
    pApplet.loadImage(path);
}
```

Within my main `draw()` loop, the background image is drawn, other images are drawn into the buffer, then the buffer is drawn:

```
pApplet.image(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
foregroundBuffer.blendMode(PApplet.ADD);
for (PImage foregroundImage : foregroundImages) {
    foregroundBuffer.image(foregroundImage);
}
pApplet.image(foregroundBuffer, 0, 0);
```

The glitchy images appear only briefly, when the application starts up.  I believe that may `foregroundBuffer` being drawn to the screen before being properly initialized, and that other operations block the main thread long enough to see the glitch while initialization is happening.

This is a scaled-down copy of the background image:
[image]

Comment: It looks interesting.  Leave it in as a 'feature', or charge extra for it:)

Comment: This looks like a mismatched assumption about the dimensions of the image - i.e. if you take the second "uber" row and shift it left (moving the left hand side back up to the right end of the first "uber" row, then do the same with the third "uber" row, but shifting twice, it looks like things should start to match again...

Comment: @twalberg, maybe...i figure it's something along the lines of each 8x8 chunk being intact, but the order in which they're read has changed.  some "metachunks" along the coastline at left (that's Marin County, CA -- a NW/SE coastline) look like they're put together with coordinates inverted, as [d3...d0, ... a3...a0], with each chunk within inverted in the same way.  i think that inversion is responsible for making the edges of each über/meta/chunk legible.

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but JPEGs are segmented into 8x8 blocks.  Is there JPEG compression happening anywhere in your render stack?

Comment: @johncarl, i don't believe so.  the image is loaded as a PNG.  i haven't posted my code yet because i've had difficulty isolating the relevant part, since a lot of the rendering is abstracted away within Processing's JOGL implementation.  will do so when i have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation: When your program starts the memory used by your buffer is probably "uninitialized". It means that it contains anything that was physically left there by its previous user (task, process, system, driver, whatever).

The memory there is managed by the system by chunks with a minimal size, usually some bytes are used to chain the blocks and to record the block length, then there is the actual data.

When you display the "uninitialized" buffer, you actually display these chunks (interpreting the leftaway link/size/content as image data) and when there is a sequence of quite small chunks they produce this effect.

Comment: your description of uninitialized memory is pretty much what i was thinking, but i'm curious specifically about the fragmentation into chunks of multiples-of-8 on a side.  i figure it has to do with memory spaces as bytes, but dunno where to go from there.